# Type 2 comparator locking on ringing

Tags: oscillator, comparator, pll

I have successfully designed a 4046 IC with a phase 2 comparator locking to an external 10 MHz VCOCXO. The circuit is simple

vcoxco---->
divide by 10-->
Schmitt Trigger -->
divide by 10 -->
divide by 10 -->
IC4046 ----------->
back to vcoxco EFC pin

The comparator frequency as well as the reference signal are 10 kHz. However, I have a ringing problem starting from the OCXO itself and even if when arriving at the comparator the ringing is very limited, looks like it is locking on the ringing and NOT on the rising edge of the reference signal. Locking time is good, under 10 seconds.

[image]

[image]

(Image from a previous version of this paper: "PLL Performance, Simulation, and Design"
https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/snaa106c/snaa106c.pdf )

Now, I am not sure if I can remove it with a better loop filter charging pump or I need to search the cause somewhere else. Even if looks like it's stable I don't like the idea that is locking on a noise signal and not the real rising edge.
I was thinking can be related to ground loop self-inductance of the probe which causes resonance
leading  to ringing, overshoots or undershoots after fast signal edges.

Comment: We need a schematic. What's your target loop bandwidth? What's your design gain and phase margin at the loop bandwidth. With it being a VXCO locking to 10 MHz, presumably it's very narrow? The schmidt appears to be in the wrong place, if needed at all, it's certainly superfluous after a digital divider. You need to cite the source of your ringing illustration, if it's not your own artwork.

Comment: Hi @Neil_UK , schematics needs to be done yet, the illustration is from the papers I use for the PLL Type 2 https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/snaa106c/snaa106c.pdf (maybe an older version)

Comment: let me put some parts together and write more details . Will leave the question open for now

Comment: Interesting link snaa106c - but very patchy. He takes until p318 to get to phase margin versus time domain behaviour - that's on about page 3 of the book I never did get around to writing - loop stability is the #1 thing you must have in PLL design and the easiest to get wrong. And that diagram doesn't appear in that link, though fig 28.1 on p248 is similar. Cite it in your question properly, not tacked on in comments.